# Custom elements are not loading in anpother angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-elements

I have created simple custom elements in angular in one project and created bundle using npx-build-plus and generated files as shown in the picture below,

[image]

out of these files i took out main.js file.
I created another angular cli project and included generated js file in root folder like the below

[image]

and in index.html i used like this

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Custom Angular Element</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="elements/main.f23021e9a099929ed5cb.js"></script>
<h1 id="result" style="text-align: center"> Angular elements !!!</h1>
<value-button text="Value Button" value="1"></value-button>
</body>
</html>
```

But the element is not displaying.
I tried to give in app component html also but not working there as well

Should i give any configuraration in package.json ? Can you please tell help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following this article https://medium.com/swlh/build-micro-frontends-using-angular-elements-the-beginners-guide-75ffeae61b58

Also if try building it without an hash so that it is easy to always read that.Also you should be adding the custom element in the index.html (e.g. ).

The article talks about setting these things up in more detail.